# Hibernate proxy object not working for superclass methods

Tags: java, hibernate, javassist, mappedsuperclass

We have a web application that uses Hibernate. After upgrading the codebase to Hibernate 3.6 (from 3.3.2) I've found that the proxy data objects generated by Hibernate only return the correct value for some methods. It seems that methods in a concrete data model class work fine, but methods in `@MappedSuperclass` abstract superclasses are not working.

Here is the data model we have:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class DataObject implements Serializable {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, columnDefinition = "serial")
    private int id;

    // getter, setter, equals, hashcode implementations here
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class SecuredDataObject extends DataObject {

    @Version
    @Column(name = "Version")
    private int version;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "SecurityId", nullable = true)
    private Integer securityId;

    // getters, setters here
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AuditedDataObject extends SecuredDataObject {

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "CreatedDate", nullable = true)
    private Date createdDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "LastUpdateDate", nullable = true)
    private Date lastUpdateDate;

    // getters, setters here
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Form")
public class Form extends AuditedDataObject {

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Name", length = 200, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Path", length = 80, nullable = true)
    private String path;

    // getters, setters, other properties and methods here

}
```

This worked OK in Hibernate 3.3.2, but after the upgrade to Hibernate 3.6 the application has gone awry. The following test code illustrates the problem:

```
    int formId = 1234;
    Form form = (Form) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(Form.class, formId);

    System.out.print("id = ");
    System.out.println(formId);
    System.out.print("getId() = ");
    System.out.println(form.getId());
    System.out.print("getSecurityId() = ");
    System.out.println(form.getSecurityId());
    System.out.print("getVersion() = ");
    System.out.println(form.getVersion());
    System.out.print("getLastUpdateDate() = ");
    System.out.println(form.getLastUpdateDate());
    System.out.print("getCreatedDate() = ");
    System.out.println(form.getCreatedDate());
    System.out.print("getName() = ");
    System.out.println(form.getName());
    System.out.print("getPath() = ");
    System.out.println(form.getPath());
```

The output of that code is:

```
id = 1234
getId() = 0
getSecurityId() = 182
getVersion() = 0
getLastUpdateDate() = null
getCreatedDate() = null
getName() = Form name here
getPath() = /path/here
```

Four of those methods have returned incorrect results: getId(), getVersion(), getLastUpdateDate() and getCreatedDate() have returned 0 or null. The actual row in the database has non-zero / non-null values. However getName(), getPath() and most curiously getSecurityId() have worked fine.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Is it a fundamental problem with mapped superclasses, or is there another reason why this could occur?

Note that the `Form` object returned by Hibernate is a Javassist proxy - if viewed in a debugger it typically has a class name like `Form_$$_javassist_15` etc.

---

**Update:**

This problem seems to be occurring in Hibernate, not Javassist. I switched over the bytecode generation to CGLIB by setting `hibernate.bytecode.provider=cglib` in hibernate.properties, but get exactly the same erroneous results with CGLIB in place (and confirmed CGLIB is working because the class name returned by Hibernate becomes `Form$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4f3b4523`).

I'm still no closer to identifying why it's going wrong, though.

Comment: Maybe you need to file a bug report. If you have a test that proves this unexpected behavior and you've isolated the test only to Hibernate, then this is a good candidate for a bug report. Usually the Hibernate team will challenge you "Prove it by providing a test" :)

Comment: I was my fault, because some getters and setters were `final`. However I couldn't find a warning about doing this in the Hibernate documentation, so I might report a documentation problem. The documentation does warn about final classes, but not final methods...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer: some of the getters and setters on the superclasses were marked `final`.

In hindsight this is obvious... because the methods were final, the proxy classes couldn't override them. So the solution is to remove `final` from any getters and setters in mapped superclasses.

Here are the getters and setters that were defined on `SecuredDataObject`:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class SecuredDataObject extends DataObject {

    @Version
    @Column(name = "Version")
    private int version;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "SecurityId", nullable = true)
    private Integer securityId;

    // Note - method IS NOT final
    public Integer getSecurityId() {
        return securityId;
    }

    public void setSecurityId(Integer securityId) {
        this.securityId = securityId;
    }   

    // Note - method IS final
    public final int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public final void setVersion(final int version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

It explains why my test was returning `securityId` correctly but was not returning `version` correctly — `getVersion()` was `final` whereas `getSecurityId()` was not.

So in summary, don't mark your getters and setters as `final` if Hibernate might try to proxy them!